# How to excecute a .sh program with old date

Tags: time, execute-command

How can i make a .sh file that will run another .sh file on a old date like...

Set date to 2014/06/03
run .sh file
set date back to real time

Answer (score 1):

Use this  preload library https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime ... you need to compile it from source, but everything is very well documented

It might not work with comercial software to cheat trial period etc.  You can specify time: absolute or relative... Downsides of absolute time are covered in documentation. In general it works well...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date -s STRING` or `date --set=STRING`, where string is a date in human-readable format, for example `date --set="2014-06-02"`. From `man date`:

```
DATE STRING

The  --date=STRING  is  a mostly free format human readable date string
such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29  16:21:42"  or
even  "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items indicating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative  time,  relative date, and numbers.
```